# cannot load library via jni

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a Java project with jni and the native part works fine. I need to load a pre built (built using ndk) .so file from within my jni c file, using dlopen().

But, I get the following dlerror : Cannot load library: load_library[1093]: "system/lib/mytestlib.so" Library  not found

JNI Code:

```
void* handle = dlopen("system/lib/mytestlib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
if(handle == NULL)
{
        char* er = dlerror();
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, TAG, "dlerror: %s", er);
}
```

The funny thing is, if I try to load any other prebuilt lib from the phone's /system/lib folder it loads it without error. Also I can even open my .so with fopen without issues, so the path is correct. The fact that its only happening to my lib is really bugging me. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The library path in the error message is different than in the code snippet..

Comment: That sounds like you have a dependency issue. Does mytestlib.so depend on other shared libraries? And are they all accessible?

Comment: the .so file was made from a very simple c file. it just contains a single function called 
    void func(int *i);
which simply assigns a value to *i. No dependancies at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss / before `system`. You should provide an absolute path, you cannot rely on current directory being filesystem root. Luckily though , `/system/lib` is on [LD_LIBRARY_PATH](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen), therefore you can write

```
void* handle = dlopen("mytestlib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

Comment: thanks it worked. Apparently you don't even need to add the -ldl flag or link the ldlib library in the Android.mk file for the jni project.